# Android inner classes not being garbage collected because of this$0 variable

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, inner-classes

I am a beginner to Android but I seem to be running across a problem where my Activities are never being garbage collected because there is a still a reference to the Activity in the non-static inner class of my thread the variable is called this$0 I found it by using the MAT in Eclipse.  Below is my current setup.

```
public class MyActivity
-->class MySurfaceView
---->class MyThread
```

When trying to find information on if it was possible to remove this last instance it appears I can't after finding a very useful article [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

> Avoid non-static inner classes in an activity if you don't control
>   their life cycle, use a static inner class and make a weak reference
>   to the activity inside. The solution to this issue is to use a static
>   inner class with a WeakReference to the outer class, as done in
>   ViewRoot and its W inner class for instance

So it seems like I shouldn't use this system of inner classes or use WeakReferences.

My question is, why do the sample projects use the inner class system with no WeakReferences? Are they still garbarge collected?  Or were they designed not to deal with garbage collection?

Is it likely my application has a code problem, meaning I should correct my code and still keep my inner classes?  Or should I seperate the classes (or introduce WeakReferences)?

Comment: An inner class holds a reference to its outer class. Are you cleaning up your `MyThread` properly when the activity is destroyed, i.e. interrupting and ensuring that it dies?

Comment: Your question is really about the *outer* class not being garbage-collected.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner classes make them static and have a Weak Reference the parent.
Also store long living objects in Application Context.

Comment: thanks for your reply, why do the sample projects not do this?